# Python 3.4 : create updated new file from existing file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to loop through all lines in the master.txt file and return all lines that have '10-K' or '10-Q' in them.  I am returning all lines in the output.

```
newMasterCIK = []

with open('master.txt') as f:
    data = str.splitlines(f.read())
    data = list(data)
    for eachLine in data:
        if '10-Q' or '10-K' in eachLine:
            newMasterCIK.append(eachLine)

myfile = open('fin_index.csv', 'w', newline='')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(newMasterCIK)
```

This is the format of the file I am looping through:

```
1000032|BINCH JAMES G|4|2015-06-02|edgar/data/1000032/0001209191-15-049043.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4/A|2015-05-14|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-019826.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-04-22|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-016100.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-04-22|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-016102.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-04-22|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-016104.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-04-22|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-016106.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-04-22|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-016108.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-04-22|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-016112.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-04-29|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-016862.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|4|2015-05-14|edgar/data/1000045/0001140361-15-019824.txt
```

Comment: `if '10-Q' or '10-K' in eachLine:` is the same as `if True or ('10-K' in eachLine):`. Is this the only problem, or is there more?

Comment: Also, how comes none of those lines seem to contain those strings?

Comment: those lines contain those strings? OOH NVM... i took a sample and those just happen to be some lines that won't be included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your code seems to be this line:

```
if '10-Q' or '10-K' in eachLine:
```

Python will interpret this as `if ('10-Q') or ('10-K' in eachLine):`, which is the same as `if True or ('10-K' in eachLine):`, which is the same as `if True:`. Instead, try this:

```
if '10-Q' in line or '10-K' in line:
```

---

Also, the way you are doing it now you get the lines that match the condition, and then write them *as one single, comma-separated line* using CSV. Instead, you should either use CSV for both, reading and writing, or not at all. Finally, instead of collecting the matching lines in a list, you can just write them to the output file directly.

```
# without CSV
with open('master.txt') as f_in, open('fin_index.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if '10-Q' in line or '10-K' in line:
            f_out.write(line)

# with CSV for both
with open('master.txt') as f_in, open('fin_index.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='|')
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='|')
    for line in reader:
        if line[2] in ('10-Q', '10-K'): # assuming the number is in column 2
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: I understand, but I get an IndexError:list index out of range

Comment: @AranFreel In the CSV version? Are you using the right delimiter? Or are there empty lines in your file? Just check that the line is not empty before testing `line[2]`

Comment: Worked beautifully, I just had to take the header off of the document.  Thank you!

Comment: @AranFreel You can also "skip" the reader by doing `next(reader)` once before the `for` loop. or `writer.writerow(next(reader))` so it ends up in the output file, if you want that.

Comment: Could you add this onto the answer?  What if I wanted to loop through one csv file's values to check to see if they are in eachLine of fin_index.csv file?  I tried to convert the csv to a list then loop using the list but it didn't work.

Comment: @AranFreel What exactly do you mean? I have the impression that this is going to be more complex; maybe you should post this as another question.